# Error in expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

Can anyone help me with the following error?

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   Int32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

[image]

Below is my code, I am trying in several ways to fix this error, but I have not been successful:

```
public IEnumerable<Dia1> GetPendenciasByUser(int centroId)
{
    var query = Db.Dia1S
        .Join(Db.Cadastros, dia1 => dia1.PatientId, cad => cad.PatientId, (dia1, cad) => new { dia1, cad })
        .Join(Db.Randomizacao, dia1 => dia1.dia1.PatientId, rand => rand.PatientId, (dia1, rand) => new { dia1, rand })
        .Where(s => s.dia1.dia1.dtd1 == null ? (Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now - s.rand.RandomizacaoData)) > 1 : (Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDateTime(s.dia1.dia1.dtd1) - s.rand.RandomizacaoData)) > 1 )
        .Select(s => s.dia1.dia1)
        .ToList();
    return query;
}
```

Comment: @4castle Sorry, I already translated into English.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` can't be transformed into SQL.

Comment: It's not duplicate expensive dear friend

Comment: In what way is this not a duplicate?  Don't simply assert it isn't, give a reason or edit your question with additional information to distinguish it.  It sure looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: How do I confirm something I did not do? The posts are totally different. Sorry, but it's not duplicated. @Amy

Comment: They have the *same problem*.  It doesn't matter whether the code is the same.

Comment: Your error tells that int32.ToInt32(precise: Convert.ToInt32 in your case, boils down to the same) is not supportet in LinqToEntities. That's exactly whats mentioned in the linked (possible) duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear, LINQ doesn't know how to convert the `Convert.ToInt32()` function to SQL. You can either use direct casting like this:

```
(int)(DateTime.Now - s.rand.RandomizacaoData)
```

Or you'll have to execute the query and get the data, then convert it in memory using `Convert.ToInt32()` as you wish.